# N house on the street with M people in each one. A person is calling random numbers, probability he won't be caught when called K times already?

Tags: probability

In my case there are 7 houses with 3 people in each one. What is the probability that the kid won't be caught when he already called 4 times. He doesn't call the same number, and when the number is called the whole house knows about the kid. So if he calls 1 person it's basically like 3 people know about him.

Obviously all possible event are 21 choose 4, but what are the positive events? I was thinking about 3 choose 1 * 4 but obviously that's not correct. The answer should be around 0.474.

I was also thinking about 3/21*3/18*3/15*3/12

Also on the same note, what's the probability that he WILL get caught calling the 4th time?

Edit: To clarify my question: What's the probability he won't be caught when he called first, second, third and forth time

Comment: Well, it seems there are $3\times 3 + 4\times 2 = 17$ people that he might call, and $3\times 3$ of these are safe.  so I'd have said the answer was $\frac 9{17}$.  But perhaps I don't understand the rules.

Comment: @lulu 7 houses and 3 people living in each one. 7x3 = 21 people he can call

Comment: No, he has already used $4$ numbers so there are $21-4=17$ numbers he might call.

Comment: @lulu What I mean in my question is what is the probability he won't be caught when he called 4 times. Meaning he's not caught calling the first, second, third and forth time

Comment: Ah, that's different.  Might want to edit the post.

Comment: can you clarify your question. I'm not sure why is it so important that each house has 3 people? you wrote that if 'the number is called - the whole house knows about the kid".

Comment: Actually you are quite correct when you use the multi-hypergeometric distribution with $\displaystyle \frac {\binom {3} {1}^4 \binom {3} {0}^3} {\binom {21} {4}} \times \binom {7} {4}$. You just miss the last term: To pick out 4 houses first. (because you are just requiring any 4 different houses but not specific 4)